# ADB2C Social Log in - what is the difference between alternateSecurityId and userIdentity?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, aad-b2c

I'm just getting confused bec I have seen examples of using alternativeSecurityIds and others using userIdentities?  Are they one and the same?

Also, I want to update my [azure ad multi-tenant federation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-azure-ad-multi-tenant?pivots=b2c-custom-policy) using userIdentity instead of alternativeUserId, can I use **any name** for the **issuer** or does it need to take the value of **PartnerClaimType="iss"** like below?

```
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="issuer" PartnerClaimType="iss" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The underlying Identity structure is the same.

Yes, I agree - very confusing.

The [samples](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples#account-linking) refer to userIdentities but the documentation still refers to [alternativeSecurityId](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/social-transformations).

The feedback I have got is that userIdentities are the way to go.

**Update**

```
<ClaimsTransformation Id="CreateAlternativeSecurityId" TransformationMethod="CreateAlternativeSecurityId">
    <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="issuerUserId" TransformationClaimType="key"/>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProvider" TransformationClaimType="identityProvider"/>
    </InputClaims>
    <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="alternativeSecurityId" TransformationClaimType="alternativeSecurityId"/>
    </OutputClaims>
</ClaimsTransformation>
```

As you can see from above, that is how the identities are stored.

The post you linked to shows:

```
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProvider" PartnerClaimType="iss" />
```

So if you change it, it won't match an entry in the table.

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate the response.  I updated my post, by any chance do you know the answer to my issuer question?

Comment: Issuer can use any value. It just must never change. The sample maps it from the iss claim incoming from AAD.

Comment: Awesome thanks @JasSuri-MSFT, I appreciate the response.